# Gitlab's API (GET /projects/:id/repository/tree) throws 404 page not found

Tags: git, gitlab

According to GitLabs API documentation to get a repository tree via restful api call I should do the following, this excerpt is from the documentation which can be found [here](http://api.gitlab.org/repositories.html), it says that

> List repository tree
>
> Get a list of repository files and directories in a project.
>
> GET /projects/:id/repository/tree Parameters:
>
> id (required) - The ID of a project
>
> path (optional) - The path inside repository. Used to get contend of subdirectories
>
> ref_name (optional)-The name of a repository branch or tag or if not given the default branch

But when I do call to the above web service it returns

> 404 The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

I call `http://myserverurl/api/v3/projects/:id/repository/tree?private_token=myprivatetoken` and I get 404, of-course I pass the id of the project here which is an integer like 4, 5, 6 etc.

All the other API's work fine except for this one, is there something I am missing here?

These are my error logs from the `production.log` file

```
Started GET
"/api/v3/projects/:id/repository/tree?private_token=mytoken&id=4" for
at 2013-06-13 12:48:36 +0530 ActionController::RoutingError (No route
matches [GET] "/api/v3/projects/:id/repository/tree"):
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in
`call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in
`call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in
`call_app'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in
`block in call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in
`tagged'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in
`call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in
`call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in
`call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in
`call' vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in
`call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in
`forward'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in
`fetch'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in
`lookup'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in
`call!'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in
`call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in
`call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in
`call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in
`method_missing'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in
`call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:64:in
`block in call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in
`each'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in
`call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/puma-2.0.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:66:in
`call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/puma-2.0.1/lib/puma/server.rb:364:in
`handle_request'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/puma-2.0.1/lib/puma/server.rb:243:in
`process_client'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/puma-2.0.1/lib/puma/server.rb:142:in
`block in run'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/puma-2.0.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in
`call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/puma-2.0.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in
`block in spawn_thread'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Gitlab API page ""Status Code" section](http://api.gitlab.org/#status-codes) mentions:

```
404 Not Found
```

> A resource could not be accessed, e.g. an ID for a resource could not be found

So either the id is incorrect (which it shouldn't be if other API calls succeeds).

Or '`tree`' isn't enough, but a path should be provided (unless the project tree is empty).

Or there is some kind of permission issue which would prevent, on the server, the API to access the content of that repo.

But if the issue persists for *any* path, then it is worth to add that case to the [list of GitLab issues](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues).

As the OP mentions, that is also an **indication that the API isn't available in the code**.

Comment: I am able to call GET /projects/:id/repository/branches, the moment I append /tree to the url, it returns 404.
Also the project tree is not empty.
May be its a permission issue, but how can I solve that?

Comment: @ArifNadeem if there is a "no route matches...", it is more a ruby rails app configuration error, and not a permission error. I'll keep digging.

Comment: Any solution to my problem? Is there someplace where I can ask this question and get an answer? And can you please tell me what you think is the problem with this api call?

Answer (score 2):

This was my issue, I didn't realize that this api was available only on master branch as of 19/06/2013, when I switched my branch from stable to master it resolved the above issue, to switch the branch I used

> sudo -u git -H git checkout master

Then I had to do

> sudo bundle install

to install some extra gems on master branch and then I restarted `nginx` and `gitlab` using `sudo service nginx restart` and `sudo service gitlab start` and finally that seemed to resolve all api issues I had.

Comment: Excellent. +1. Sorry for the late answer but I wasn't available until now.

Comment: @VonC Thank you for your time, I appreciate it, following your suggestion I posted a issue https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4340 and it solved the issue.